# Build tree : how to format a parent and children list in python

Tags: python, list, tree

I need to change the format of a list following a tree structure where a parent can have multiple children (not a binary tree).

Each node in my tree follow this structure: `[my_id, my_parent_id]`

What I want:

```
[my_id, my_parent_id, [my children, [my 
    grandchildren, [...]]]]
```

(where my children, grandchildren is also in the form of `[my_id, my_parent_id]`)

I could make a program to format like this but I wanted to know if there are already any way to do this.

Here is the output of my application:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 5]]
```

What I want :

```
[[0, 0, [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0, [6, 5]]]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is very unclear. What should `my children` be? How are you trying to create this structure, starting from what? Please clarify.

Comment: In my tree every nodes follow the [an object, a player, my_id, my_parent_id] structure. 
I'm making a game tree from a game for the minmax algorithm, this is where come from my data. my_id is the number of the current node and my_parent_id is the id of the parent node.
So, my children should by [an object, a player, my_id, my_parent_id] like the parent

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code which generates something like what you want.

It starts by generating an arbitrary list of objects with the `my_id/my_parent_id` structure and ends up with just `parent` containing the rest as children/grandchildren.

```
class Nim:
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        self.name = 'Bot'
        self.my_id = my_id
        self.parent = 0
        self.children = []
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.children:
            return str( (object.__repr__(self), self.name, self.my_id, self.parent, self.children) )[1:-1]
        return str( (object.__repr__(self), self.name, self.my_id, self.parent) )[1:-1]

def generate_some_objects():
    objects = [Nim(i) for i in range(7)]
    objects[0].name = 'Human'
    objects[6].name = 'Human'
    objects[6].parent = objects[5].my_id
    return objects

def find_parent(objects):
    for nim in objects:
        if nim.my_id == nim.parent:
            return nim

def generate_hiearchy(objects):
    indexed_objects = {nim.my_id:nim for nim in objects}
    for nim in objects:
        if nim.my_id != nim.parent:
            my_parent = indexed_objects[nim.parent]
            my_parent.children.append(nim)

objects = generate_some_objects()
print('ALL:', objects)

parent = find_parent(objects)
print('Parent:',parent)

generate_hiearchy(objects)

print('Parent:',[parent])
```